# how to use apply() on df.groupby() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I know how to use aggregate functions such as mean, sum, etc. using groupby() in pandas, but I was wondering how I can use apply() to further apply a function I want.

For instance, in this data set there are two companies '1st' and '2nd':

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'], 
        'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd','1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'], 
        'name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze', 'Jacon', 'Ryaner', 'Sone', 'Sloan', 'Piger', 'Riani', 'Ali'], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'name', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
```

I want to add a column which maps the first alphabet of the name and the count of the occurrence of that alphabet. For instance:

```
list(df.groupby(['company'])['name'])
[('1st',
  0      Miller
  1    Jacobson
  4       Cooze
  5       Jacon
  8       Sloan
  9       Piger
  Name: name, dtype: object),
 ('2nd',
  2        Ali
  3     Milner
  6     Ryaner
  7       Sone
  10     Riani
  11       Ali
  Name: name, dtype: object)]
```

I want a grouped pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
company name_dict
1st     {'M':1, 'J':2 ..}
2nd     {'M':1, 'R':2, 'A': 1..}
```

I would know how to derive the name_dict if the data frame was a list using for loop, but how can I apply the function that derives the column using pandas groupby? What should be the input of that function?

For instance, let's say the function is

```
def get_name_dict():
 ...
```

What should be the intput, and how can I map the function to the pandas data frame using groupby?

Added: The reason I am asking this question is because apply() works faster than for loop, there are about 70K rows in this data frame, and using a list and for loop is not efficient.

Comment: question - apply is essentially a for loop. If that is what you want, why not just run the process in plain python?

Comment: @sammywemmy The data frame has 70K rows, and apply() works faster than for loop, that is what I know

Comment: interesting. I'd  differ on that, especially for string manipulation. To your question though, you can apply the function just like you would with `apply` function. Do you have the function already, so we can test and see where some edits or improvements could be?

Comment: @sammywemmy I am asking then about what the input should be -- should the input of the get_name_dict() be a list or a series? Would it work if I write the function as if the input is a list of names?

Comment: why do you want a dataframe of dictionaries?

Comment: not sure. I know apply would act on each column

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way around it, iterating through the grouping, which is what apply would do :

```
{key: value.str[0].value_counts().to_dict()
for key, value in df.groupby("company").name}

{'1st': {'J': 2, 'M': 1, 'P': 1, 'S': 1, 'C': 1},
 '2nd': {'R': 2, 'A': 2, 'M': 1, 'S': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `collections.Counter`

```
import collections

df.name.str[0].groupby(df['company']).apply(lambda x : [collections.Counter(x)]).str[0]

Out[119]: 
company
1st    {'M': 1, 'J': 2, 'C': 1, 'S': 1, 'P': 1}
2nd            {'A': 2, 'M': 1, 'R': 2, 'S': 1}
Name: name, dtype: object
```